# Ruby on Rails - If Statement to Find Any Child with Current User ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a site where users act as judges who can score submissions. Models:

```
Scores
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :submission

Submissions
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :scores
```

The Score Index page is basically the judging dashboard. It lists each submission the judge is assigned to score. If the judge has not scored the submission yet, a link displays to the New Score page under that submission. If the judge has already scored the submission, the link will instead take them to the Edit Score page.

I need to figure out how to tell the app whether to display the new score link or the edit score link.

My first if statement:

```
<% if submission.scores.count == 0 %>
  <p><%= link_to 'Score/View This Entry', new_submission_score_path(submission) %></p>
```

If the submission does not have ANY scores, no problem, that definitely means the judge has not created a new score. But, what if the submission has other scores, not from the current user? How can I construct the next `<% elsif %>` statement to show the New Score link if none of the submission's scores contain the current user's ID? (being `:user_id` in the score table)

Thank you--I am on Rails 4 if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
submission.scores.where(:user_id => submission.user_id).empty?
```

Comment: Almost! I need to find a match with the current user's ID, so I have tweaked it thusly:

<% elsif submission.scores.where(user_id: current_user.id).empty? %>

Comment: That definitely works though, thanks so much! Glad it was a simple solution.